# CSS Sticky position not working properly on mobile

Tags: html, css, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I have a button on my OpenCart (2.3.0.2) website with a sticky cart button. The idea is that there is only one page to order from (Just a few sandwiches, no categories and product page needed) so I added a cart button that stays on the top right of the page:

```
#cart {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

This works on the desktop site but on mobile I get the following when scrolling:[image: Button on mobile]
As you can see on the top right, the button scrolls up a bit. After this the button scrolls with the page.

Are there any fixes for this issue?

Answer (score 7):

This is related to the issue at [Position fixed on chrome mobile causing element to move on scroll up/down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679794/position-fixed-on-chrome-mobile-causing-element-to-move-on-scroll-up-down)

Solution:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the first that comes up for "*position sticky not working on mobile*"

But only this helped me resolve my problem:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

**EDIT**:

Good news: this also works without: `user-scalable=no`! Thank you [Umut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18102751/umut) for pointing this out. I also took out the `maximum-scale=1.0`, so for accessibility it makes better sense.

Comment: According to the [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) usage of `user-scalable=no` can cause accessibility issues. Since we are in the diversity and inclusion age we need to be more careful.

Comment: Thank you @Umut for pointing this out. I've updated my answer accordingly, and the code still works well.

Comment: Hey @iorgv thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

```
#cart {
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
}
```

Have you tried position sticky rather than fixed?

A sticky element toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed).